# Is Sloane's Gap due to random chance or human factor?

Tags: probability

Sloane's Gap is a gap in the graph of the function illustrating the number of occurences of an integer in oeis. I was wondering if such a gap would form if we generated random sequences or if it is the result of a human factor.

Answer (score 4):

It is due to human factor, things like interest in primes and prime powers. If the OEIS were simply a website of random integer sequences, the gap would not appear.